# Изменение параметров HttpClientHandler для одного HttpClient

Tags: c#

Я делаю несколько запросов создавая для каждого HttpClient так

```
public class HttpRequest {
        public string Request(string method, string url, string content, string content_type, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string proxy, int timeout, bool auto_redirect, CookieContainer cookie_container) {
            WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy();
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            if (proxy.Length != 0) {
                string proxy_url = proxy.Split(new char[] { '@' })[0];
                webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy_url);
                if (proxy.Split(new char[] { '@' }).Length == 2) {
                    string proxy_auth = proxy.Split(new char[] { '@' })[1];
                    if (proxy_auth.Split(new char[] { ':' }).Length == 2) {
                        webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxy_auth.Split(new char[] { ':' })[0], proxy_auth.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1]);
                    }
                }

                httpClientHandler.UseProxy = true;
                httpClientHandler.Proxy = webProxy;
            }

            httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = auto_redirect;
            httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookie_container;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
             
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
                
            foreach (var item in headers) {
                if (!request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(item.Key, item.Value)) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Не удалось добавить заголовок в запрос ({item.Key} = {item.Value})");
                }
            }

            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout);

            if (method == "GET") {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            } else if (method == "POST") {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                    
                var content_dict = content.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(part => part.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => Uri.UnescapeDataString(split[1]));

                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content_dict);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(content_type);
            }

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.Send(request);
            var responseString = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseString.Result;
        }
}
```

Но возникает проблема утечки соединений.

Я попытался создать один экземпляр HttpClient, чтобы это исправить.

```
public class HttpRequest {
        public static HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        public static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        public string Request(string method, string url, string content, string content_type, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string proxy, int timeout, bool auto_redirect, CookieContainer cookie_container) {
            WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy();
                
            if (proxy.Length != 0) {
                string proxy_url = proxy.Split(new char[] { '@' })[0];
                webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy_url);
                if (proxy.Split(new char[] { '@' }).Length == 2) {
                    string proxy_auth = proxy.Split(new char[] { '@' })[1];
                    if (proxy_auth.Split(new char[] { ':' }).Length == 2) {
                        webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxy_auth.Split(new char[] { ':' })[0], proxy_auth.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1]);
                    }
                }

                httpClientHandler.UseProxy = true;
                httpClientHandler.Proxy = webProxy;
            }

            httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = auto_redirect;
            httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookie_container;

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
                
            foreach (var item in headers) {
                if (!request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(item.Key, item.Value)) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Не удалось добавить заголовок в запрос ({item.Key} = {item.Value})");
                }
            }

            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout);

            if (method == "GET") {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            } else if (method == "POST") {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                    
                var content_dict = content.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(part => part.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => Uri.UnescapeDataString(split[1]));

                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content_dict);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(content_type);
            }

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.Send(request);
            var responseString = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseString.Result;
        }
}
```

Тут тоже возникла проблема, HttpClientHandler можно задать один раз и если мне нужно изменять прокси и прочие параметры под каждый запрос, то у меня не получится это сделать, будет ошибка `This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request`. Может быть есть пути решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Покажите класс целиком, не жалейте буквы, они бесплатные. Оба способа, само собой неверные.

Comment: `несколько запросов создавая для каждого HttpClient так` - а теперь идем в документацию и видим там `HttpClient предназначен для однократного создания экземпляра и повторного использования в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения`, после думаем, о каком `несколько запросов создавая для каждого HttpClient так` может идти речь..?

Comment: @aepot исправил

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну мало ли что там написано. Тот же IHttpClientFactory склоняет к частому созданию HttpClient (пусть даже переиспользуя хендлеры). Но это никак не дает решения. Если у нас 30 проксей, то как сделать одновременно 30 запросов, если прокси задается в хендлере не создавая 30 хендлеров...

Comment: @vitidev Фабрика весьма умно дает вам клиент на один конкретный ресурс, этот клиент поддерживает соединение и не плодит новое. Если вы на 30 одновременных запросов будете делать новый клиент, то у вас будет висеть куча соединений, которые будут ждать таймаута и жрать ресурсы и забивать лимит. Вы можете почитать об этом например [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/424873/). Если вам прям так хочется сделать новый клиент, то делайте, не запрещают, но только тогда, когда уверены на 100%, что текущий не используется и закрыл все соединения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в упор не вижу как фабрика решает проблему одновременного использования проксей, где для каждого прокси нужен свой хендлер. Также не считаю подход с фабрикой особо умным, ведь HttpClient (который выдала фабрика) может быть захвачен синглтон сервисом и ни на какие DNS не реагировать, но обсуждение работы фабрики и что она решает - оффтоп. Вопрос про прокси.

Comment: @vitidev Про фабрику заговорили вы, я вам лишь дал ответ почему там позволительно создание новой копии, ну и чем вообще самостоятельное создание нового клиента чревато. Я вроде про прокси даже и не отвечал, не? К чему тогда эти "в упор не вижу"? А я в упор не вижу смысла использовать 30 запросов с разными проксями, что теперь делать будем, ворчать друг на друга? Короче, предлагаю этот спор на корню сразу зарезать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну вы же спросили "несколько запросов создавая для каждого HttpClient так может идти речь". Еще и человека в документацию ткнули. А я и отметил, что документация в данном случае не является последней истиной, а уж проблему автора вообще не затрагивает. Так что после моего замечания и не нужно было развивать тему )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Про асинхронность забыли. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).
- При использовании прокси нужно создавать отдельный клиент на каждую прокси. Перенастраивать прокси на уже созданном клиенте невозможно. Но и создавать из-за этого клиент на каждый запрос не следует.
- Не используйте строки типа `"GET"`, когда есть перечисление, так будет сложнее ошибиться.
- Для `FormUrlEncodedContent` не надо задавать `ContentType`, этот класс сам его задаст правильно.

Создайте пул клиентов на свой список прокси и отправляйте по несколько запросов через каждый.

Пример кода:

```
public class HttpRequest : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public HttpRequest(string proxy, int timeout, bool autoRedirect = true, CookieContainer cookieContainer = null)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        if (proxy?.Length > 0)
        {
            string[] tokens = proxy.Split('@');
            string proxy_url = tokens[0];
            WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy_url);
            if (tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                string proxy_auth = tokens[1];
                string[] authTokens = proxy_auth.Split(':');
                if (authTokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(authTokens[0], authTokens[1]);
                }
            }

            handler.UseProxy = true;
            handler.Proxy = webProxy;
        }

        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All; // добавляет заголовок gzip, deflate, br автоматически и автоматически распаковывает ответы сервера
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = autoRedirect;
        handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer ?? new CookieContainer();

        httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(string query)
    {
        var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        return collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => collection[k]);
    }

    public async Task<string> RequestAsync(HttpMethod method, string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, Dictionary<string, string> query = null)
    {
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);

        foreach (var item in headers)
        {
            if (!request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(item.Key, item.Value))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"Не удалось добавить заголовок в запрос ({item.Key} = {item.Value})");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }

        if (method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(query);
        }

        using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        httpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Использовать как-то так

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("https://proxy.com:3128", 3000);
var query = httpRequest.ParseQueryString("hello=world&param=123");
string result1 = await httpRequest.RequestAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "example.com", headers, query);
string result2 = await httpRequest.RequestAsync(HttpMethod.Get, "example.net", headers);
```

Но вообще вы пытаетесь сделать суперуниверсальный метод, который может всё. Из-за этого он становится супер сложным. Сделайте лучше отдельный метод для GET, отдельный для POST, даже можно несколько под разные Content-Type, типа форму, JSON, XML и т.д.

Как разберетесь с этим до конца,  вот тогда принимайтесь за `IHttpClientFactory` и более тонкие настойки `SocketsHttpClientHandler`.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно попытаться прочить данные, как вы раньше сказали, если часто возникает ошибка ```System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.``` в строке ```using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);```? Это действительно проблемный прокси, потому как без него ошибки нет. @aepot

Comment: @Александр лучше задайте отдельный вопрос. Оно вам вообще надо? Проксей мало?